# What is the proper response when someone says "I am hurt"?

Tags: word-request

English is so flexible, there are too many ways to express "**hurt**"

> [transitive, intransitive] **[hurt (somebody/something/yourself)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hurt_1?q=hurt)** to
>   cause physical pain to somebody/yourself; to injure somebody/yourself
>
> He hurt his back playing squash.
>
> Did you hurt yourself?
>
> Stop it. You're hurting me.
>
> My back is really hurting me today.
>
> Strong light hurts my eyes.
>
> My shoes hurt—they're too tight.
>
> **hurt** [intransitive] to feel painful
>
> My feet hurt.
>
> Ouch! That hurt!
>
> It hurts when I bend my knee.

---

> **[hurt](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hurt_2)** (adj) injured physically
>
> None of the passengers were badly hurt.

Let's say you are playing with your child and then she says "**I am hurt**". What are your response?

**Where does it hurt?**

**Where do you hurt?**

**What hurts you?**

**What hurts?**

**Where are you hurt?**

**Where is it hurt?**

Comment: [Where is it hurt? That would refer to an animal for example. Buzzer]

Comment: I don't think many native speakers would often say ***I am hurt*** when they mean ***I'm [physically] injured***. That particular phrasing is ***far*** more likely to carry the somewhat more metaphorical sense of *My **feelings** have been hurt*. To which an appropriate response might be ***I'm really sorry if I have upset you*** (assuming you really ***do*** regret whatever hurtful thing you did or said). But "What's an appropriate response" is far too open-ended to be a sensible question here on ELL.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I saw this movie "the-knight-before-christmas" when the girl Vanessa Hudgens hit the man while driving her car, she got off & said: 

Are you ok?

I couldn't see anything

Are you hurt?
https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=the-knight-before-christmas

Comment: @Tom: I never suggested that *Are you hurt?* wasn't a "natural" way of asking if someone has been injured. But to be honest, if the addressee replied with *Yeah, I am hurt* I might still interpret that as (facetiously?!) meaning *I'm not **physically** hurt, **but my feelings are***. There are several written instances of [*“Was she hurt?” “Not physically.”*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+she+hurt+not+physically%22) in Google Books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English speakers do not tend to say "I am hurt" as a response to physical pain.

"I am hurt" tends to refer to *emotional* hurt, ie *hurt feelings*.

A more idiomatic way to express that you have been hurt, certainly in British English, would be "*I hurt myself*", or to specifically name the body part you hurt, for example, "*I hurt my hand*".

However, all of your suggested responses seem perfectly fine.

Comment: I saw this movie "the-knight-before-christmas" when the girl Vanessa Hudgens hit the man while driving her car, she got off & said: 

Are you ok?

I couldn't see anything

Are you hurt?
https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=the-knight-before-christmas

Comment: @Tom Yep, "are you hurt" is often asked, but I can't explain why "I am hurt" - at least without further context - is not usually used for physical hurt.